# Commodore – The Inside Story

Tags: history, commodore, books

Commodore – The Inside Story, by David Pleasance, who was a manager in Commodore UK. Sounds like a very interesting book, supposedly available, but when I look on Amazon, hoping in particular for the Kindle edition (which hopefully would be more reasonably priced than the hardback), it claims to only have the book in Italian.

What's up with this? Is there a way to buy this book, ideally in electronic form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It’s available directly from [the publisher](https://downtimepublishing.com/) (the author’s own publishing company), including [in electronic format](https://downtimepublishing.com/products/e-book-pdf) (e-pub and Mobi).